# Issues installing pyzmail or imapclient on python 3.5, pip throws a value and syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, exception, pip, imapclient

I am trying to download a couple of packages in python 3.5 but pip keeps throwing an exception(via pip install pyzmail), please see below:

How do I overcome this issue?

> Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:\users\chiruld\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "c:\users\chiruld\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
>       requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
>     File "c:\users\chiruld\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\pip\req.py", line 1229, in prepare_files
>       req_to_install.run_egg_info()
>     File "c:\users\chiruld\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\pip\req.py", line 292, in run_egg_info
>       logger.notify('Running setup.py (path:%s) egg_info for package %s' % (self.setup_py, self.name))
>     File "c:\users\chiruld\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\pip\req.py", line 265, in setup_py
>       import setuptools
>     File "c:\users\chiruld\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\setuptools__init__.py", line 2, in 
>       from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
>     File "c:\users\chiruld\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\setuptools\extension.py", line 5, in 
>       from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
>     File "c:\users\chiruld\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\setuptools\dist.py", line 103
>       except ValueError, e:
>                        ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Tell the developer to rewrite it for Python 3.x.

Comment: That is not the problem, but thanks for the input.

Comment: It looks like c:\users\chiruld\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\setuptools\dist.py is written for Python 2. The `except ValueError, e:` syntax is only Valid in Python 2. In Python 3 it needs to be written as `except ValueError as e:`.

Can you provide more detail on the commands you're using to install pyzmail and/or imapclient? I'm the maintainer of IMAPClient and I know it does install and function on Python 3.5. This looks to be some sort of environmental issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows.., try right clicking 'cmd.exe' and select 'Run as Administrator' and click 'Yes' to allow the following program to make changes to this computer.